# How to check if a list contains items from another lists sublist?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I know this question has been asked several times here and I went through most of them but for some reason I am unable to utilise those solutions for my current issue.

I have a list with 11 sublists: 
`list_a = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5].....[11,12,13]]`

I also have a randomly generated list of length 9 within the range of 1 and 13:

```
list_b = [1,4,7,8,2,3,8,9]
```

I want to create a function that iterates through the sublists of list_a and returns true only if all the items within the sublist are present in list_b. I tried the 'all' function but it doesn't seem to work in my case here as it takes all the items within the list and not the sublist.

```
for i in list_a:
    if all(a in i for a in list_b):
       print ('Yes')
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `I tried the 'all' function but it doesn't seem to work`: How did you try it? Post your code so that we can comment on it.

Comment: @Selcuk Apologies. I have updated the question with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just got your `all()` logic twisted around. You need to check if each item in the sublist is in `list_b` (rather than checking if each item in `list_b` is in the sublist).

Change your `all()` logic to:

```
all(a in list_b for a in i)
```

As an aside, it would be a bit more efficient and simplify things if you changed `list_b` to a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been stuck at this since the last hour.

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is right, but you are checking if elements in `list_b` exist in sublists of `list_a`, while your requirement is the inverse of it. You can use `set` operations here:

```
>>> list_a = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[11,12,13]]
>>> list_b = [1,4,7,8,2,3,8,9]
>>> all(set(a).issubset(set(list_b)) for a in list_a)
False
```

or

```
>>> list_a = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,8]]
>>> all(set(a).issubset(set(list_b)) for a in list_a)
True
```